# Strange tokens in Penn Treebank 3.0 sentences

Tags: python, nltk

I have gotten LDC99T42-EnglishTreebank corpus from LDC. Now I am trying to load it and get the sentences using NLTK...

I used BracketParseCorpusReader to load the .mrg files, then called 'sents()' function to get sentences. But there are something strange in the sentences (looks like labels, such as *T*-1 and *U*).

For example:(from 09/wsj_0925.mrg)

```
[u'Computer', u'Sciences', u'Corp.', u'said', u'0', u'it', u'received', u'a', u'U.S.', u'Postal', u'Service', u'contract', u'that', u'\*T*-1', u'will', u'have', u'a', u'value', u'of', u'at', u'least', u'$', u'33', u'million', u'\*U*', u'.']
```

Could you tell me why this happens...? And how to load the corpus correctly?

#Update

I find that all these tokens come from "-None-" nodes in parsed file. Should I delete all those node? Or is there any way to ignore them?

Comment: [This?](https://github.com/rastle/144coursework/blob/master/Homeworks/Homework%206/treebank_3/parsed/mrg/wsj/09/wsj_0925.mrg#L14)

Comment: @erip Yes, the "-None-" node. Sorry I'm not able to reply or @ you...